# argument defaults to a precedent argument's value

Tags: c++, arguments

I vaguely remember that it was possible to write something like:

```
void f(int a, int b=0, bool c=!val);
```

if some extra stuff was written at the beginning of the arguments list. The example in GCC gives error of `val` non declared in scope.
Unfortunately, I cannot find any reference on the Internet, so I ask here.

Comment: The only way I know this is possible is if `val` is a `const` value in the scope of the function (perhaps a class enum or global const variable).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about overloading f()? It won't be a problem whether val is const or not.

```
void f(int a, int b, bool c);

void f(int a, int b=0) {
   f(a,b,!val);
}
```

Comment: for also other reasons I decided already to use your approach.